# How to represent the graph in terms of parameter in specific requirement?

Tags: user-behavior, graphs

The requirement is each and every user get rewarded based on some task. If completed successfully,then user will get some amount in terms of Reward. Now I want to display how many new members are there in the system and what is total number of user. I want to display these numbers weekly and monthly. In weekly case, I have the solution but in terms of month its difficult for me to use same approach (i.e used in weekly users).

Here I attached example. In below image, 2 graph are there which has 7 bars(i.e 7 days = week). On mouse hover on each bar it will give name & number (i.e  Mon,17) which will gives info that 17 new users get registered on monday.`

But what could be in terms of month? If I use same approach then what will be these 7 bars? or is there any other idea to represent monthly & total new users?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use 7 bars for a week because that makes sense (7 days in a week).

You cannot use 7 bars to represent a month because that does not make any sense (you recognised that).

As a suggestion, look at this a different way.

Think about changing the granularity as you move further way from the current period, e.g.

- Weekly View - 7 days in a week (7 bars)
- Monthly View - 4 (or 5) weeks in a month (4 or 5 bars)
- Annual View - 12 months in a year (12 bars)

Obviously you will need to adapt your visualizations to match these, which might involve alternative layouts to fit within your space constraints.

Comment: I already know that 7 bars in case of monthly graph is not possible. That's why I ask for the another solution. Have you any other suggestion except this? Because I already know this. Anyways thank for your suggestion.

Comment: Don't use vertical bars for every visualization :-)

For inspiration I recommend reading Stephen Few's book Information Dashboard Design.

Comment: Also, be careful about using mouse-over to display additional information because not everyone will use a mouse. Use mouse-click to trigger the display of additional information so that everyone can use this solution.